# How do I get rid of an equipped item?

Tags: dead-cells

I accidentally picked up a skill (Pollo Power) with a modifier that makes me take 100% extra damage from enemies. I got it early in the run and I don't have another skill to replace it. How do I get rid of the equipped skill so I can stop taking double damage?

[image: Equipment screen showing double damage modifier]

Answer (score 1):

There are many discussions online, like on [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588650/discussions/3/1621726179586315119/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/deadcells/comments/8f3l7e/dropping_items/), where people are complaining that items can't be dropped.

This probably works as intended, in this way you can't exploit cursed items just dropping and equipping them when you want.